# how to restore a database if there is not any database to restore to it

Tags: c#, sql-server

i am asking this question because i do not know what to search.

you know there is a database that we restore back up file to it. if database deleted what we can do? for example we developed a program. and we backed up the database info's. after that all files of us such as database and software deleted(not backup file). now if we later want to restore database using backup file and we do not have database(MDF file) what we can do now?

thanks.

Comment: Create a blank database.  Restore to that.

Comment: thanks for answer. how can i do that? what is the command for it? thank you

Comment: @gjmkdyttyhujk:- There is no single command. You have to follow certain steps. Check  the link which is added in my answer else check n8wrl answer!

Comment: SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) may be the ticket here. Take a look at the [Restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.aspx) class. No guarantees because I've never used SMO, but a long time ago I  used SMO's COM predecessor (DMO) to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a blank database and restore using the backup file to that database.

Check the [Restore a Database Backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177429.aspx) or details.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Management Studio, right-click on the 'databases' node. Pick "Restore database."

Click "device" and then the browse button on the far-right.

Browse for your .BAK file and double-click on it.

Once selected, pull-down on the 'database' under "destination." You should see the database in the backup. Select it.

Change any settings - log/mdf destination, etc. and GO!

This is how we deploy new staging servers from production backups all the time.

Comment: I **think** (because OP tagged his question with C#) that he wants to do it somehow automatically (for example during a setup or with unattended installation) so Management Studio _may_ be not a viable option for him.

Comment: exactly. i want to do this programmatically not with ssms.